# Rails UJS - Select clicked element in js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

How do I select the clicked element with jQuery - using $(this), etc. - in the js.erb file response from the server?

I have a table of projects and would like to be able to insert a new project right below the row that I clicked the "Add project" button on.  If possible, I would like to use a generic jQuery selector and not have to rely on specific css id's.

Here is my projects table:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="active">
   <th style="width:31%">Project</th>
   <th style="width:42%">Notes</th>
   <th style="width:10%">Due</th>
   <th style="width:8%">Priority</th>
   <th style="width:3%"></th>
   <th style="width:3%"></th>
   <th style="width:3%"></th>
  </tr>
 <% @projects.each_with_index do |project, index| %>
  <tr id="row-<%= index + 1 %>">
   <td><%= project.title %></td>
   <td><%= project.notes %></td>
   <td><%= project.due_date %></td>
   <td><%= project.priority %></td>
   <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="#">Del</a></td>
   <td><%= link_to "+", new_project_path(@project, :row => index + 1), :remote => true, :class => "add-project" %></td>
  </tr>         
 <% end %>                      
</table>
```

Here is my create action:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    @project.save
    respond_with(@project)
end
```

Here is my create.js.erb file:

```
$(this).closest("tr").after("<%= j(render "new_project_row") %>");
```

And here is my new_project_row partial:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= @project.title %></td>
    <td><%= @project.notes %></td>
    <td><%= @project.due_date %></td>
    <td><%= @project.priority %></td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Del</a></td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
```

No errors are being thrown.  The new project is being added to the database correctly, but the new row is not being inserted into the projects table.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already passing the `:row` in your create action save that to an instance variable so its available in your view.  Then in your js.erb you can do

```
$("##(@row)").after("<%= j(render "new_project_row") %>");
```

Since it will actually be the `id` of the given `tr` you should just be able to call after directly.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am looking for a way to select that row with pure jQuery if possible.